# Unable to create audio file with AudioFileCreateWithURL()

Tags: c++, core-audio

I'm trying to create a new file on disk and record to it using the Core Audio framework on OSX. My main hurdle right now is that I cant seem to create the file using the following code. My objective is to figure out why the below code doesnt work so that I can resume working on the rest of my project. You can see the output of this code below.

```
string fp = "…path…to…file.../file.wav"  
CFURLRef audioFileURL = CFURLCreateFromFileSystemRepresentation(
        NULL,
        (const UInt8 *)fp.c_str(),  // filename
        fp.length(),             // number of bytes in filename
        false               // this is a file, not a directory
);

if(audioFileURL == NULL){
    cout << endl << "audioFileURL == NULL :(";
}

OSStatus retErr = AudioFileCreateWithURL (                                
                        audioFileURL,                                        
                        df.mFormatID,                          
                        &aqData.mDataFormat,                                 
                        kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,                           
                        &aqData.mAudioFile                                   
                        );
cout << endl << "\nAudioFileCreateWithURL error:" << retErr;
```

which outputs the following:

```
AudioFileCreateWithURL error:1954115647
```

I'm not having any luck finding out what this error means. Any help here is apprecaited.

Answer (score 0):

Core Audio errors come back as either a number or a 4 letter code.  I'm guessing the weird number you show is the memory location of a code.

You need something like this to determine and convert:

```
    static char *FormatError(char *str, OSStatus error)
    {
        // see if it appears to be a 4-char-code
        *(UInt32 *)(str + 1) = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(error);
        if (isprint(str[1]) && isprint(str[2]) && isprint(str[3]) && isprint(str[4])) {
            str[0] = str[5] = '\'';
            str[6] = '\0';
        } else
        // no, format it as an integer
        sprintf(str, "%d", (int)error);
        return str;
    }
```